# Why must I use an anonymous wrapper for this jQuery chain?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$('p').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

But why can't I do any of these?:

```
$('p').fadeOut(300, $.fn.remove);
$('p').fadeOut(300, $().remove);
var p = $('p'); p.fadeOut(300, p.remove);
```

Comment: Because it expects a function?

Comment: @Jack I am passing it a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('p').fadeOut(300, $.fn.remove);`

`$.fn.remove` is passed with no context. `$.proxy($.fn.remove, $("p"))` would work here

```
$('p').fadeOut(300, $().remove);
```

passed with no context.  `$.proxy($().remove, $("p"))` would work here

```
p.fadeOut(300, p.remove);
```

passed with no context. `$.proxy(p.remove, p)` would work here

So fixing the code:

```
$('p').fadeOut(300, $.proxy($.fn.remove, $("p")));
$('p').fadeOut(300, $.proxy($().remove, $("p")));
var p = $('p'); p.fadeOut(300, $.proxy(p.remove, p));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gtv85/

Comment: Yes, this is right. I expected it to work because the context is the element, but it isn't the jQuery-wrapped element. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxHowell when you pass any function naked somewhere, it will lose any context when it is called on the other end. They will call it like `fn()` <-- there is no method call, so there is no context. `$.proxy` and `Function#bind` work around this, returning a function with permanently bound context.